# Weighted Average of Uniformly Distributed RV

Tags: uniform-distribution, convolution

Let $x \sim U[0,1]$ and $y\sim U[0,1]$. Let $z= \omega\, x+ (1-\omega)\,y$, where $\omega\in[0,1]$. The pdf of $z$ is a trapezoidal distribution over $[0,1]$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f(z)&= \left\{\begin{array}{cl} 
\dfrac{z}{\omega (1-\omega)} &\text{if}\,\,\,z \in[0,\min\{\omega, 1-\omega\}]  \\[0.08in]
\dfrac{1}{\max\{\omega, 1-\omega\}} &\text{if}\,\,\,z \in(\min\{\omega, 1-\omega\},\max\{\omega, 1-\omega\}]  \\[0.08in]
\dfrac{1-z}{\omega (1-\omega)} & \text{if}\,\,\, z \in(\max\{\omega, 1-\omega\},1].
\end{array} \right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
I am searching for the conditional pdfs $f(z|x)$ and $f(x|z)$ (or the joint $f(z,x)$). How should I proceed?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243887, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190469, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/.

Comment: @whuber These are about the sum of uniforms, I am interested in the weighted average.

Comment: The weighted average is a sum of uniforms having potentially different upper limits, that's all.  For instance, when $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $\omega\gt 0$ then $\omega X \sim U(0,\omega).$

Comment: @whuber Thank you that was helpful.

Comment: Concerning the new question, you can follow the procedures given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210394 which concern a slightly more complicated version of your question.  The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584874 also is related (with uniform distributions replaced by exponential distributions).